# ng-repeat with two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a array  which is of the form

```
$scope.vehPermitTypevalue = [ [ "NP","National Permit"], ["IND_AP","Andra Pradesh"]];
```

HTML CODE:

```
 <ui-select name="permit" id ="permit" multiple ng-model="vehicle.selectedPermits"  on-select="getVehiclepermitId($item)"   ng-disabled="disabled" class="w-md mb-10">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a Permit Type in the list...">{{$item[1]}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="permittype in vehPermitTypevalue | filter:$select.search">
      <span ng-bind-html="permittype | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

In Drop down I need Only the  "National Permit" , "Andra  Pradesh " but it is displaying like NP,National Permit AP, Andra Pradesh in a drop down .

I have changed my code to display on "national Permit" I did like this

```
 <ui-select name="permit" id ="permit" multiple ng-model="vehicle.selectedPermits"  on-select="getVehiclepermitId($item)"   ng-disabled="disabled" class="w-md mb-10">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a Permit Type in the list...">{{$item[1]}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="permittype in vehPermitTypevalue[index][1] track by $index | filter:$select.search">
  <span ng-bind-html="permittype | highlight: $select.search"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

then not able to display any items in drop down.

After selecting any option it is displaying properly like "national permit" with "X"  mark to delete i did {{$item[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxJdz.png)}}.

here i am attaching pics

[image]

After selecting i am getting like this due to {{$item[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxJdz.png)}}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="permittype in vehPermitTypevalue track by $index | filter:$select.search">
  <span ng-bind-html="permittype[1] | highlight: $select.search"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
```